# Does the use of Memcached to store PHP variables involve any writing to the hard disk drive?

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached

Since this is what I am trying to do. I want to make some variable values available to a PHP script. The values are fetched from the internet every minute (they change). I do not want the values to be written and written again to the SSD. Does Memcached do the job of storing them at any given time on system memory only, with no SSD writing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, memcached only stores things in local memory. If you restart the service any data inside is lost.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Memcache can be set to enable some sort of logging. But most have this disabled by default.

The values are all stored in memory but some log of the action may be written

Modern ssds have much better write wearing systems so you shouldn't have to sorry about writing to ssd